# What does the saying “Don’t feel pregnant” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, etymology

My dad sometimes says “Don’t feel pregnant” when I tell him how I’m feeling. For instance, I’ll tell him “I feel like all I do is work”, he’ll say “Don’t feel pregnant”. I think it may mean “ Don’t feel like you’re the only one” or something similar. I’ve looked the saying up online and can’t find a true meaning or etymology of it. My fiancé says he’s never heard that saying. Does anyone know? 
My dad is 69, we are American, and speak English, for reference. I am unsure of our nationality. I know his grandfather (maternal) was a  full-blooded Cherokee Indian, last name Barton.

Comment: Ask your dad why he says it. Are you American by any chance? What is your dad's  dialect or mother tongue?

Comment: We are American and speak English. I will ask him lol. He will more than likely say, “I don’t know. That’s what Mama (or Daddy) used to say”... I am very interested in knowing : )

Comment: It could be a pun, a "dad joke" if you prefer, on “don't fall pregnant”. If he is the son of immigrants  we might get closer to the mystery. I have not heard of this line, and I am quite old! Come back and let us know :)

Comment: I just asked and he said, “Me, I guess” lol

Comment: Mary, thank you!!! I was hoping an older person may be able to help me!! My dad is 69, so I’m sure he heard it when he was younger.

Comment: Hmm, 69... I'm not that old but I'm getting there. I think this question is off-topic for learners of English. I could ask a mod to migrate this over at English Language & Usage, which handles questions about the origin of phrases and different English dialects in greater depth.  Could you specify in the question (not in the comments because they might get deleted in the migration)  your nationality, your dad's age and which state he comes from.

Comment: This is my first time using this site. I did not know there are specific categories to which it applies when posted... I apologize! You made a great suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/ if you like its vibe  but if you do post something make sure the question has detail and looks like you did some research e.g Googling and dictionary links.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: I suggest you ask someone who speaks Cherokee.

Comment: The mod message told me that you have to request the migration yourself. Can you see the link beneath your post that says "flag"?  Click on the option that says *in need of moderator intervention*  and  explain you would like the post to be migrated.  Normally, when a post is better suited to EL&U the mods do this without prompting but  the mod(s) is not convinced :)

Comment: As an aside, you are likely quite sure of your **nationality** (what country you're a citizen of) but more likely unsure of your **ancestry** (information about your ancestors).

Answer (score 3):

I am 70, born and raised in the USA, Caucasian, Protestant, middle class. We used this phrase a lot when I was young; I mainly remember hearing and saying it in high school in the mid- to late ‘60’s. It means “You’re not the only one,” “It’s not that big a deal.” It’s like a shrug . . . a “meh.”

Answer (score 2):

This saying is similar to "dont feel special."  You told him you feel like you work all the time,  everyone feels that way so dont feel special.  That's how I take the saying.  I'm assuming it's not a commonly used because well, its rude.

Comment: It's best on this learners' site not to use dont and its (for it's).